# grep command in searching wildcards

Tags: linux, unix, sed, grep

```
askljasklj.
twuikso lsliosus.
sakjsiua .sfdds* askhkjash.
```

Here I want to grep lines containing `.*` pattern.
Using command `cat file | grep ".\*"` is giving output `sakjsiua .sfdds* askhkjash`, but this should not be output or I am using the wrong command

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have the words in a file foo. Hence giving a command:

```
    cat foo | grep ".*"
```

Would print everything. If you just want .* pattern then use the below command:

```
    cat foo | grep "\.\*"
```

By putting \ we can making . and * to behave as a normal text character

Comment: @PrinceGarg: Both `.` and `*` are [metacharacters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter). You need to escape them so that `grep` can read them as normal text characters. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

you should escape them both as below:

```
grep "\.\*" yourfile
```